# Image not show in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use a PNG as my background,a little large about 1.6M. when I put it in drawable-hdpi,it can show normally on the devices except Android 6.0. It's strange.But if I put the picture in drawable-xhdpi,it can show normally on all devices. Otherwise,if I change the picture in draw-hdpi to a little size,about 800kb,it can also show normally. That really confuse me so much, I want to know the reason.

Comment: maybe not support for android 6.0 ? or image too large

Comment: but why I change a folder to xhpi and it worked?

Comment: well... i'm not into android 6.0... yet. but please make a low-res copy of your image and locate it TWICE for each resolution (xhdpi and hdpi).. you may save memory and increase performance that way + that would always work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on device resolution. Drawable folders are used to avoid put too large images in small screen device and cause out of memory or put too small images in high definition screen device what would cause an strange image. I advice you  create different image sizes and put in drawable folders: drawable-mdpi, drawable-hpdi, etc... Your app will load better and it can attend different screen size devices. Problem is not android version.

Comment: thank you,I do have different folders.That's only an experiment,I just want to find the reason.And I think maybe you are right